# MATE visually show active window

Tags: mate, window

Is it possible to visually dim nonactive windows in Ubuntu MATE, using the default Marco window manager? Is it possible to with a different window manger?

I work with multiple monitors with many windows open/tiled that I alt-tab between.

I would like the active window to be immediately obvious.

With default Ubuntu MATE (with any of the "appearances" choices) the only visual indication of a window being active is that the header bar of the application different color.

I would like inactive windows to be slightly grayer. in order to make the active window stand out visually from the other windows.

Thank you!

Comment: Good question, you may want to ask it also on https://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible in the default Ubuntu Mate 20.04 window compositor (Marco).

But it is possible after switching to the compton compositor. Just selecting compton in the Mate Tweak setting didn't work for me, but others have different workarounds that worked for me:

I followed

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/better-compton-compositing-better-than-other-choices-too/6260